# Beginner Clojurist Lazy Sequence error: Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long

Tags: clojure, lisp

I am new to Clojure and Lisp, but love it so far. I am currently trying to understand lazy-seq's and Clojure's ability to define infinite sequences. I have the following code:

```
(defn geometric
  ([] geometric 1)
  ([n] (cons n (lazy-seq (geometric (* n 1/2))))))
```

If I run:

```
(geometric)
```

in my REPL, it returns 1, as expected. However, if I run,

```
(take 10 (geometric))
```

I get the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from:
java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom
```

What I expect to get is:

```
(1 1/2 1/4 1/8 1/16 1/32 1/64 1/128 1/256 1/512)
```

Why am I getting this error? If I've understood correctly, one should be able to cons n to the lazy-sequence, and take should return the first ten values of the sequence, evaluated recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small typo in your code:

```
(defn geometric
  ([] (geometric 1)) ;; notice the added parens around geometric 1
  ([n] (cons n (lazy-seq (geometric (* n 1/2))))))
```

Without this fix `(geometric 1)` was working because the implementation was to evaluate expression `geometric` (just a function value) which was discarded, then `1` expression was evaluated and returned as the function result (it was the last expression in this arity function body).

Now it works as expected:

```
(take 1 (geometric))
;; => (1)

(take 5 (geometric))
;; => (defn geometric
  ([] geometric 1)
  ([n] (cons n (lazy-seq (geometric (* n 1/2))))))
```

Notice that you cannot just call `(geometric)` safely in REPL as it will  try to evaluate an infinite sequence.

Answer (score 4):

One of my favorite functions: `iterate` takes a function `f` and a value `x` returning `x, (f x), (f (f x), (f (f (f x)))` etc.

Here is an elegant implementation with the same functionality:

```
(defn geometric []
  (iterate #(/ % 2) 1))
```

Not a direct answer to your question but hopefully informative!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```clj
([] geometric 1)
```

This expression means that, if `geometric` is called with no arguments, two things will happen:

1. The symbol `geometric` will be evaluated, which will result in the `geometric` function.
2. The number `1` will be returned.

What you probably meant was this:

```clj
([] (geometric 1))
```

This means that calling `(geometric)` is equivalent to calling `(geometric 1)`. Your example will now work as expected:

```clj
(take 10 (geometric))
;=> (1 1/2 1/4 1/8 1/16 1/32 1/64 1/128 1/256 1/512)
```

Answer (score 1):

`(geometric)` evaluates to the number 1, not to a sequence. `(take 10 1)` gives the same error that you're seeing now.

You should try running `(take 10 (geometric 1))`, since `(geometric 1)` will produce a sequence which can be supplied to the second argument of `take`.